# How to create active directory user with UserPrincipalName length more than 20 chars

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Is there any way to create AD user account from C# code with `UserPrincipalName` length more than 20 chars?

I tried to do it with

```
userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = username@domain.com
```

but got an error

> A device attached to the system is not functioning.

At the same time user account with `userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = username` (< 20 chars) creates successfully.

Comment: Are you setting the `samAccountName` separately? I know that this has to be <= 20 chars - so maybe AD is just using your `username` (before the `@domain` part) as its samAccountName, if you don't explicitly set that - and this attribute has to be <= 20 chars

Comment: Thanks a lot, @marc_s! I just assigned samAccountName separately with length <= 20 chars, as you said, and it works!

Comment: @marc_s , could you submit your comment as answer? Then I can close the question and accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the `userPrincipalName` has no limitation to 20 characters.

Are you setting the `samAccountName` of that user separately?

I know that this attribute has to be <= 20 chars - so maybe AD is just using your username (before the `@domain` part) as its `samAccountName`, if you don't explicitly set that - and the `samAccountName` has to be <= 20 chars.

Answer (score 0):

This is restricted because of backwards compatibility for older versions of AD. This restriction can't be overwritten programmatically.